# Telerik App Builder Device Simulator not showing preview

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone, telerik-appbuilder

I am developing Hybrid App using with [Telerik Appbuilder](http://www.telerik.com/appbuilder).
I got warning from AVG Antivirus and forced me to delete file.
As I deleted file, it disappeared Tab Strip from Device Simulator.
I uninstalled Telerik Appbuilder and restarted my pc then again Installed Telerik Appbuilder but Device Simulator showing nothing.

[image]

Same thing I installed on other machine it is coming nicely as in snapshot.

[image]

Can anybody help me what happened after AVG file delete action & how can I restore my previous ideal working condition on my local machine (as it is working fine on new machine but not on my local machine).

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Explorer, go to %LOCALAPPDATA%\Telerik and delete the BlackDragon folder, if present.

It should work then. If not, uninstall AppBuilder again...again delete that folder...reinstall!

Comment: Yes, It did worked for me, go to **%LOCALAPPDATA%\Telerik** and then delete **BlackDragon** folder but again **AVG anti virus** popping up, asking for delete file again but for stand by I just disabled AVG Anti virus to get working on.

Is there any more solution to get rid off this problem permanently even enabled AVG anti virus.

Comment: I don't know about AVG, but can you tell it to explicitly ignore the file(s) it is flagging?

Comment: After your kind suggestion, I am able to continue development on my local machine :):)